# enumerate with indent for paragraph only

Tags: enumerate

I am using this code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm,itemindent=.5cm,labelwidth=\itemindent]
\item Item one
\kant[1-2]
\item item two
\kant[3-4]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

to make the itemized text appear as the normal text, but there is no indent for new paragraphs. I am trying to create something like this :

```
1. item one with it's own paragraph.
  New paragraph under item one
1. item twowith it's own paragraph.
  New paragraph under item two
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[11]
\begin{enumerate}[wide, labelindent=0em, listparindent=2em] % <---
\item Item one
\kant[2-3]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```